# Topogram graph edges not visible

Tags: javascript, python, meteor

I'm using [Topogram](http://topogram.io) project to visualize my IoT network. I just ran the example they provided [here](https://github.com/topogram/topogram-api-client). I can see the nodes but edges are not shown in the browser.
[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQyPu.png)

In the python script they provided for the example,a message prints that it created 20 edges. However, they are not visible on the web interface. Also you can see it shows 0 edges in the top right corner of the interface.

Is there anyone else who use this project and faced this problem? I have very little knowledge about javascript, so I am unable to resolve this issue myself. Also if you happen to know any other projects with a python API which can do the same as this project, I also welcome suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself.
It seems to be a bug in the Topogram project.Since I am not familiar with JS I did not attempt to fix it. However, I have found a way to make the edges visible.
It seems to be the graph should have high number of nodes and edges to show the edges because of the bug. I have first created large number of dummy nodes and edges. Then deleted all of them and filled with my actual low number of nodes and edges. The edges became visible. Hope this will help someone!